# JavaHL on two separate JBoss Web Applications LinkageError: Already Loaded by another class loader

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, tigris

We have two separate instances of the same web application. One is a sandbox and one a live environment. Both are accessing subversion so we set up `svnClientAdapter` to use JavaHL. On the startup of the application we are calling `JhlClientAdapterFactory.setup();`

When the second instance starts I get the error message:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\msvcr100.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\msvcp100.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libapr-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libapriconv-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libeay32.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\ssleay32.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libaprutil-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\dbghelp.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsasl.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_subr-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_delta-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_diff-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_wc-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_fs-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_repos-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_ra-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvn_client-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
Native Library C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\native\libsvnjavahl-1.dll already loaded in another classloader
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/native
```

It's pretty obvious what the problem is, but I have no idea how to resolve it.

The native libraries are loaded by the `svnClientAdapter` using the method:

```
System.loadLibrary(WINDOWSLIBS[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by deploying the needed dll with the application itself. svnClientAdapter is also using a special property `subversion.native.library` to find the dlls. So in the initialization method I'm getting the absolute path the application is running in with the following method:

```
String strPath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("someResourceThatExists").getPath();
strPath = strPath.replace("filenameOfResource");
```

Afterwards I'm adding the filename of the library and setting the property:

```
System.setProperty("subversion.native.library", strPath);
```

That seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a third "web application" whose job would be to load native libraries used by whatever other instance is deployed on the server

Comment: I guess this would work, but we have no control over which instance is running on which server, which means I can't be sure, that every instance is running with the "native lib"-instance. But I solved it in a different way. Thanks